# Desert Rose Help

Tags: diagnosis, plant-health

My Nana passed away a few years ago and she left me 4 desert roses and I love them. I have never been good with plants but I have been proud that I have not killed them. I have even repotted them once and saved one from root rot. The other day I noticed that the largest one has developed a brown spot on the caudex. The caudex isn't soft but this spot wasn't there last week. What should I do? Thank you!

[image]